# Roughly what proportion of a cloud does 'rain out'?

Tags: meteorology, clouds, rainfall

What proportion of the water in a cloud will 'rain out'?

Or, comparing the cloud before and after it has rained, what proportion of the water is left afterwards?

I really have no idea so am just looking for an order of magnitude range, is it 50%, 1% or something tiny like 0.00001%?

Edit: I wanted to leave the specifics to the answerer, but maybe an easier question is the difference in amount of water (any form) above the surface before and after rain.

Comment: I'm not sure this can be answered. For most clouds, the answer is 0%, because they don't actually generate rain. For those that do produce rain, what would constitute "100%"? Draining all the liquid droplets from the cloud? Leaving the air's relative humidity at 100%, or at the same level as surrounding air, or at zero?

Comment: @jeffB sure, anything! I do not even know enough to ask the right question, so please feel free to fill in the blanks! gansub had a useful answer but it has disappeared...

Comment: you need to give a lot more information in the question like temparature-pressure and the speed of condensation-wind speed-turbidity and lots of other information,and the answer to this will be for this spesific situation only.

Comment: I am trying to emphasise that I am looking for a vague, order of magnitude, make whatever assumptions you want answer. I understand that the question is not well defined, and the answer is extremely complex. I only want literally any tidbit of information on the topic. Fill in the blanks however you like!